# How to get the backup file name to store in database when making backup using Laravel spatie backup

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-backup

```
$doBackUp = Artisan::call('backup:run --only-db');
return back()->with('success', __('Completed!The :x has been successfully completed.', ['x' => __('database backup')]));
```

This is the backup file in storage>app>Laravel> Laravel_2023-05-04-06-31-18.zip

I want to store the the zip file name in database **Laravel_2023-05-04-06-31-18.zip**.

How do I get the name of the backup file to store in the database, as it just returns only boolean values?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe one of the events fired during the backup can be used. Check https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v8/taking-backups/events